# How to open autoselect combobox2 from onchange event of autoselect combbox 1

Tags: jquery, combobox

I am using jquery autoselect combobox plugin and might be answers are available to get value of first autoselect combobox on its onchange event but they are not working for two comboboxes on same page. Anyhelp will be appreciated. here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <style>
            .custom-combobox {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .custom-combobox-toggle {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                margin-left: -1px;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .custom-combobox-input {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            (function( $ ) {
                $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
                    _create: function() {
                        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                            .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
                            .insertAfter( this.element );
                        this.element.hide();
                        this._createAutocomplete();
                        this._createShowAllButton();
                    },
                    _createAutocomplete: function() {
                        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
                            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                        this.input = $( "<input>" ).
                            appendTo( this.wrapper ).val( value ).
                            attr( "title", "" )
                            .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                            .autocomplete({
                                delay: 0,
                                minLength: 0,
                                source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                            })
                            .tooltip({
                                tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                            });
                        this._on( this.input, {
                            autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                                alert("the select event has fired!");
                                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                                this._trigger( "select", event, {
                                    item: ui.item.option
                                });
                                autocompleteselect.trigger("change");
                            },
                            change: function( event, ui ) {
                                if ( !ui.item ) {
                                    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                        valid = false;
                                    autocompleteselect.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                        if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                            this.selected = valid = true;
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            //autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                        });
                    },
                    _createShowAllButton: function() {
                        var input = this.input,
                            wasOpen = false;
                        $( "<a>" )
                            .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                            .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                            .tooltip()
                            .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                            .button({
                                icons: {
                                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                                },
                                text: false
                            })
                            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                            .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
                            .mousedown(function() {
                                wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
                            })
                            .click(function() {
                                input.focus();
                                // Close if already visible
                                if ( wasOpen ) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                            });
                    },
                    _source: function( request, response ){
                    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                    var text = $( this ).text();
                    if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                        return {
                            label: text,
                            value: text,
                            option: this
                        };
                }) );
            },
            _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
                // Selected an item, nothing to do
                if ( ui.item ) {
                    return;
                }
                // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                var value = this.input.val(),
                    valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                    valid = false;
                this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                    if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                        this.selected = valid = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                // Found a match, nothing to do
                if ( valid ) {
                    return;
                }
                // Remove invalid value
                this.input.val( "" )
                    .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                    .tooltip( "open" );
                this.element.val( "" );
                this._delay(function() {
                    this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
                }, 2500 );
                this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
            },
            _destroy: function() {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
            }
            });
            })( jQuery );
            $(function() {
                $( "#combobox" ).combobox({ change: function() { alert("changed"); }});
                $( "#combobox_retailer" ).combobox();
                $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
                    $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
                });
                $("#combobox").change(function() {
                    alert(this.value);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
            <select id="combobox" name="combobox1">
                <option value="">Select one...</option>
                <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
                <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
                <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
                <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
                <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
                <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label>Another </label>
            <select id="combobox2">
                <option value="">Select one...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: right now my browser console shows me bracket missing issue... after the line _source: function( request, response ) there should be a '{'...

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: replace the line autocompleteselect.trigger("change"); with this._trigger("change"); and see what happens...

Comment: @Banik- thanks its working now.

Comment: okay then Im posting it as answer...plz mark it as useful...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
autocompleteselect.trigger("change");
```

with

```
this._trigger("change");
```